# Python 3 Dataclass Type Hinting for Model Object

Tags: python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I am trying to define a dataclass with a variable type of a model object how do I do it?

```
a = Model.objects.get(a_id=1)

@dataclass
class B:
    model: ???
    name: str
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the class as type-hint.

```
@dataclass
class B:
    model: Model
    name: str
```

(I suppose that your `Model` is a Django-like model class, given by the syntax of the first line of your snippet)